# sort values doesn't sort in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe but when using the `sort_values` from pandas it doesn't get sorted.

```
x = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dataset.csv', sep = ',')
x.sort_values('duration',ascending = False,inplace = True)

x.loc[:,'dates'] = pd.to_datetime(x['dates'])
b=x.sort_values(['dates'],ascending = True).groupby([x['dates'].dt.strftime('%m'),'user'])['duration'].sum().reset_index()
b
```

It should sort by duration of each user in the month as summed hours as it is already but it doesn't appear sorted.

```
  month  user   duration
0   09  user_01 54.73
1   09  user_02 55.82
2   09  user_03 18.00
```

Comment: What is the output you're showing? We need a [MCVE].

Comment: Either way, sorting before grouping is useless.

Comment: and what makes you think `b` should be sorted? you don't sort anything after grouping...

Comment: by default a `groupby` will sort by the grouping key, i.e. it will sort the index (you can disable that by adding `sort=False`, but the output will not be sorted at all)

Comment: i thought that doing sort in the same line would sort the group by simultaneously. Ok. I did it after the group by and it worked.

Comment: you learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0):

you can group first and sort the values

```
df.groupby('month').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['duration'],ascending=False))
```

Out:

```
month   user    duration
month               
9   1   9   user_02 55.82
    0   9   user_01 54.73
    2   9   user_03 18.00
```